# Aspose Java API : How to fetch Row from excel workbook which has maximum data in it

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

I want to get a row from XLSX workbook which has maximum data in it. I have the "com.aspose.cells.Cells" object of worksheet.

```
workbook = new Workbook(sourceFilePath);
com.aspose.cells.WorksheetCollection sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
Worksheet worksheets = sheets.get(0);
com.aspose.cells.Cells cells = worksheets.getCells();
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: To get a row index which has more/maximum data in it, you may write your own code and logic accordingly for your needs. For example, you may loop through rows in the worksheet and gather the data/text length of each cell then evaluate/compare which row has more data in it.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. But It will be inefficient if my excel file is too big.. I need to iterate through all rows in xlsx file to get the row which has maximum data..

Comment: Yes, it depends. If an Excel spreadsheet is big, it might take more time. I think there is no such a feature available in MS Excel, is not it? If MS Excel has this feature, please let us know with details, we may look into it and support it via Aspose.Cells API.